# SQL Server Snapshot cannot connect Subscriber server?

Tags: sql-server, snapshot

Wrong information:

> The process can not connect to Subscriber "***". (Source: MSSQL_REPL, error number: MSSQL_REPL0)
>
> SQL Server Network Interface: Error locating specified Server / Instance [xFFFFFFFF]. (Source: MSSQLServer, error number: -1)
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred when establishing a connection with SQL Server. Can not find or can not access the server. Check that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information, see SQL Server Books Online.
>
> Login timeout expired (source: MSSQLServer, error number: HYT00)

Answer (score 0):

> 1. open Sql Server Browser service
> 2. permit 1434 port  UDP

That's OK